# Why does libcurl sometimes complain 'Couldn't resolve host name'?

Tags: curl, libcurl

I write a multithread program used libcurl, But sometimes curl will complain it can`t resolve host name after exec curl_easy_perform, sometimes not.

```
size_t Http::WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    MemoryStruct *mem = (MemoryStruct *)userp;

    mem->memory = (char *)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    assert(NULL != mem->memory);
    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}

void Http::run(const URL &url, Http::FinishedCallback cbk)
{
    CURL *handle = curl_easy_init();
    if (handle) 
    {

        MemoryStruct *chunk = new MemoryStruct;
        chunk->memory = (char *)malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
        chunk->size = 0;    /* no data at this point */


        CURLcode res; 
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.getUrl().c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10L);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(handle);

        /* check for errors */
        if (CURLE_OK != res) 
        {
            chunk->status = false;
            std::string errCode = std::to_string(res);
            chunk->memory = (char *)realloc(chunk->memory, chunk->size + errCode.size() + 1);
            memcpy(&(chunk->memory[chunk->size]), errCode.c_str(), errCode.size());
            chunk->size += errCode.size();
            chunk->memory[chunk->size] = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            chunk->status = true;
        }

#ifdef _DEBUG
        chunk->url = url;
#endif
        cbk(chunk);
        free(chunk);
        curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
    }
}


void Http::get(URL url, FinishedCallback cbk)
{
    std::thread http(&Http::run, Http(), url, cbk);
    http.detach();
}

Http::~Http()
{
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

this is invocer.

```
int index = 0;
bool finish = false;
void func(Http::MemoryStruct *memo)
{
    if (!memo->status)
    {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        LOG(INFO) << "Failure:\t" << curl_easy_strerror((CURLcode)atoi(memo->memory)) << "\n";

#endif
    }
    else
    {
        //LOG(INFO) << memo->memory << '\n';
    }
    finish = memo->status;
    ++index;
}

int main(void)
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    URL::AttribMap attribMap{ { "class", "System" }, { "token", "KY0SQ3FX996PU1ZO" }, { "type", "GetConfig" } };
    URL url("open.55.la", "/index.php", attribMap);
    Http http;
    while(index++ <=10)
    {
            try
            {
                http.get(url, func);
            }
            catch (std::_System_error &err)
            {
                LOG(INFO) << err.what();
            }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        ;
    }
    el::Loggers::flushAll();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Does It may caused by data collapse？

Answer (score 8):

That's the error message libcurl returns for the `CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST` error code (6).

I'll quote the [Exit status section from the curl book](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-returns.html)

> Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host's address was not
>   resolved. The address of the given server could not be resolved.
>   Either the given host name is just wrong, or the DNS server is
>   misbehaving and doesn't know about this name when it should or perhaps
>   even the system you run curl on is misconfigured so that it doesn't
>   find/use the correct DNS server.

If this is returned intermittently for host names that works sometimes and sometimes not, it would indicate you have a broken system somehow, a DNS server that doesn't respond properly or perhaps some sort of DOS prevention wrongly tuned.

Comment: Thanks for your detail answer, **a DNS server that doesn't respond properly or perhaps some sort of DOS prevention wrongly tuned.**  may be a suitable reason, Latterly I will try to  figure out whether it was caused as your description. I also suspect that whether is was caused by thread race condition.